# How can i execute a method of a controller by doing click on a button?

Tags: html, laravel, model-view-controller, routes

I am trying to use a button to execute directly a method of a controller but it does not working

I have tried with href doing action, also with complete routes

```
<a href="{{ action('AdminCalendarController@index') }}">  TOUCH  </a>

 Route::get('task-calendar_show', ['uses'=>'AdminCalendarController@updateIndex']);

Route::post('task-calendar_create', ['uses' => 'AdminCalendarController@updateIndex2']);


Route::post('task-calendar/updateIndex', ['as' => 'task-calendar.updateIndex', 'uses' => 'AdminCalendarController@updateIndex']);


Route::get('task-calendar/updateIndex', ['as' => 'task-calendar.updateIndex', 'uses' => 'AdminCalendarController@updateIndex']);
```

also have a method index but it does not load

```
  public function index()
    {

        if (auth()->user()->id == '13' || auth()->user()->id == '15' || auth()->user()->id == '27' || auth()->user()->id == '17' || auth()->user()->id == '16' || auth()->user()->id == '10') {
            $this->tasks = Task::where('status', 'incomplete')->get();
        } else {
            $this->tasks = Task::where('status', 'incomplete')->where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)->get();

        }

        return view('admin.task-calendar.index', $this->data);
    }
```

This is the method just to return an echo

```
public function updateIndex()
{
    echo 'entro';
}
```

Action App\Http\Controllers\AdminCalendarController@index not defined.

Comment: where's route for `AdminCalendarController@index`?

Comment: This is the route for index also i have a resource route to the controller      
                                                                                               
                                                                                               Route::post('task-calendar/index', ['as' => 'task-calendar.index', 'uses' => 'AdminCalendarController@index']);

Comment: You want run  updateIndex() ?

Comment: Learn first how to do routes in laravel
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#basic-routing